# Why is template inheritance Failing?

Tags: django, django-templates

**Edit**: Please do not be mislead by this question, It was my fault that my changes where not working out. I happen to have to projects that are named the same(`not a smart idea`) this confused everything, i was making changes in a different project from that i was working in. Sorry to the good stackoverflow folks that i mislead.

I have a base template `public_base.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- [if IE ]> <html class="no-js"> <![endif] -->
<head>

  <!-- favicon for web browser and smartphones -->
  <link rel="icon" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/img.png" type="image/x-png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/apple-touch-icon.png">

  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Homenaje|Molengo' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <!-- CSS Section -->
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}maincss/bootstrap.min.css">

  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}maincss/impress.css">  
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}maincss/style.css">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}maincss/impression.css">


  <title>{% block title %}F4L | Have it easy{% endblock %}</title>
</head>

<body lang="en">

  <div id="container">
    {% load smartmin %}
    <div id="header">                                                                     <!-- Header -->
      <div id="logo">
        <a href="{% url homepage %}">
          <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/logo.jpg" class="" alt="" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="menu">
        <ul>

      {% if perms.restaurant_detail.restaurant_detail.create %}
          <li><a href="#">Join F4L</a></li>
      {% endif %}
      <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>

      {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
      <li><a href="{% url users.user_logout %}">logout</a></li>

          {% else %}
          <li><a href="{% url users.user_login %}">login</a></li>
          {% endif %}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>                                                                                <!-- End Header -->
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>

    <div id="main">                                                                       <!-- Main -->
      {% block main-contents %}
       <p>jrneflkwnel</p>
      {% endblock %}
    </div>  

  </div>
```

that i inherit here, `home.html`

```
{% extends "public_base.html" %}

{% block main-contents %}

 <p>This is not Working.</p>

{% endblock main-contents %}
```

but this is not working at all,basically the content in `home.html` is not loading. what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to inherit the block in your `home.html`:

```
{% extends "public_base.html" %}
{% block main-contents %} 
      <p>This is not Working.</p>   
{% endblock %}
```

Have a read through [the docs on template inheritence](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#id1), specifically:

> [when you inherit from a parent template] the template engine will notice the three block tags in base.html and replace those blocks with the contents of the child template.

So when you inherit from the parent template, you need to include a block in your child template that overrides a block in the parent template, in this case the `main-contents` block.

Comment: Are both templates in the root of your `templates` folder?

Comment: Is your view definitely rendering the correct template (`home.html`) and are your urls definitely working correctly (i.e. executing the correct view)?

Comment: yes everything is in check...i double checked. basically it was working before, but when i changed `public_base.html` that is the markup and so forth, it failed to load `home.html` but loads `public_base.html` fine

Comment: You have to have the path to `path/to/public_base.html` otherwise it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a empty `block content` in your `public_base.html`. Add the following code in your `public_base.html`.

```
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

Or else you have to inherit `{% block main-contents %}` from `public_base.html`.

Comment: Do you have both the templates in the root template folder defined in `settings.py` of your application?